# Set stretching parameters for images programmatically in swift for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So if we want to stretch only parts of an image, be it a regular image or a background image, we use the following settings in layout editor:

[image]

How do you set those programmatically?

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1

Comment: http://macoscope.com/blog/stretchable-images-using-interface-builder/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. as a matter of fact that's where I learned how to stretch images in the INTERFACE BUILDER. but i don't wanna do it there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413585/what-is-use-of-stretching-property-of-uiimageview-how-i-can-use-this-property

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Specifying the cap insets of your image

You can set the stretch specifics by making use of the `UIImage` method `.resizableImageWithCapInsets(_:UIEdgeInsets, resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode)`.

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> func resizableImageWithCapInsets(capInsets: UIEdgeInsets, resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode) -> UIImage
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Creates and returns a new image object with the specified cap insets
>   and options.
>
> A new image object with the specified cap insets and resizing mode.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `capInsets`: The values to use for the cap insets.
>
> `resizingMode`: The mode with which the interior of the image is
>   resized.

---

## Example: custom stretching using the specified cap insets

As an example, let's try to---programmatically---stretch my (current) profile picture along its width, precisely at my right leg (left side from viewing point of view), and leave the rest of the image with its original proportions. This could be comparable to stretching the width of some button texture to the size of its content.

First, let's load our original image `foo.png` as an `UIImage` object:

```
let foo = UIImage(named: "foo.png") // 328 x 328
```

[image]

Now, using `.resizableImageWithCapInsets(_:UIEdgeInsets, resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode)`, we'll define another `UIImage` instance, with specified cap insets (to the middle of my right leg), and set resizing mode to `.Stretch`:

```
/* middle of right leg at ~ |-> 0.48: LEG :0.52 <-| along 
   image width (for width normalized to 1.0)                */
let fooWidth = foo?.size.width ?? 0
let leftCapInset = 0.48*fooWidth
let rightCapInset = fooWidth-leftCapInset // = 0.52*fooWidth

let bar = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftCapInset, bottom: 0, right: rightCapInset)
let fooWithInsets = foo?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(bar, resizingMode: .Stretch) ?? UIImage()
```

Note that `0.48` literal above corresponds to the value you enter for `X` in the interface builder, as shown in the image in your question above (or as described [in detail in the link provided by matt](http://macoscope.com/blog/stretchable-images-using-interface-builder/)).

Moving on, we finally place the image with cap insets in an `UIImageView`, and let the width of this image view be larger than the width of the image

```
/* put 'fooWithInsets' in an imageView.
   as per default, frame will cover 'foo.png' size */
let imageView = UIImageView(image: fooWithInsets)

/* expand frame width, 328 -> 600 */
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 328)
```

The resulting view stretches the original image as specified, yielding an unproportionally long leg.

[image]

Now, as long as the frame of the image has `1:1` `width:height` proportions (`328:328`), stretching will be uniform, as if only fitting any image to a smaller/larger frame. For any frame with `width` values larger than the `height` (`a:1`, ratio, `a>1`), the leg will begin to stretch unproportionally.

---

## Extension to match the `X`, `width`, `Y` and `height` stretching properties in the Interface Builder

Finally, to thoroughly actually answer your question (which we've really only done implicitly above), we can make use of the detailed explanation of the `X`, `width`, `Y` and `height` Interface Builder stretching properties in [the link provided by matt](http://macoscope.com/blog/stretchable-images-using-interface-builder/), to construct our own `UIImage` extension using (apparently) the same properties, translated to cap insets in the extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizableImageWithStretchingProperties(
    X X: CGFloat, width widthProportion: CGFloat,
    Y: CGFloat, height heightProportion: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

        let selfWidth = self.size.width
        let selfHeight = self.size.height

        // insets along width
        let leftCapInset = X*selfWidth*(1-widthProportion)
        let rightCapInset = (1-X)*selfWidth*(1-widthProportion)

        // insets along height
        let topCapInset = Y*selfHeight*(1-heightProportion)
        let bottomCapInset = (1-Y)*selfHeight*(1-heightProportion)

        return self.resizableImageWithCapInsets(
            UIEdgeInsets(top: topCapInset, left: leftCapInset,
                bottom: bottomCapInset, right: rightCapInset),
            resizingMode: .Stretch)
    }
}
```

Using this extension, we can achieve the same horizontal stretching of `foo.png` as above, as follows:

```
let foo = UIImage(named: "foo.png") // 328 x 328
let fooWithInsets = foo?.resizableImageWithStretchingProperties(
    X: 0.48, width: 0, Y: 0, height: 0) ?? UIImage()

let imageView = UIImageView(image: fooWithInsets)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 328)
```

---

**Extending our example: stretching width as well as height**

Now, say we want to stretch my right leg as above (along width), but in addition also my hands and left leg along the height of the image. We control this by using the `Y` property in the extension above:

```
let foo = UIImage(named: "foo.png") // 328 x 328
let fooWithInsets = foo?.resizableImageWithStretchingProperties(
    X: 0.48, width: 0, Y: 0.45, height: 0) ?? UIImage()

let imageView = UIImageView(image: fooWithInsets)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
```

Yielding the following stretched image:

[image]

---

The extension obviously allows for a more versatile use of the cap inset stretching (comparable versatility as using the Interface Builder), but note that the extension, in its current form, does not include any user input validation, so it's up to the caller to use arguments in the correct ranges.

Finally, a relevant note for any operations covering images and their *coordinates*:

> **Note:** Image coordinate axes `x` (width) and `y` (height) run as
>
> ```
> x (width):  left to right (as expected)
> y (height): top to bottom (don't miss this!)
> ```

Comment: thanks buddy, great answer. although I sense a little bit of sarcasm in `---programmatically---` :-D

Comment: @mnVoh Happy to help! No sarcasm intended, actually, I was trying for emphasis; but perhaps I'm misusing the `---` (em dash —) symbol as a non-native English speaker :) (In e.g. Latex, `---` translates to an [em dash symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash)).

Comment: well even if it was sarcasm, i think it's good once in a while :-D . Also I tested the code and it worked flawlessly, but one mistake that I made at first ( due to not paying close attention to your code ) was that I used the fraction values (ex. 0.48) instead of exact width values (ex. 20 pt).

Comment: @mnVoh Glad that it worked! But indeed, the cap insets (as shown in my original answer) are not directly translatable to the stretching properties in the interface builder. I added an `UIImage` extension to my answer, however, that should work as a wrapper for the cap insets, with an interface corresponding to the stretching properties of the Interface Builder. Happy coding!

Comment: How do I stretch an image only vertically, my image is something like a dotted vertical line and I need it to be stretched. I tried playing with different combination for all four parameters but its not working. In this case what values should I put for all four parameters?